# Why do i get “Permission denied” errors from using Weston/Wayland

Tags: raspberry-pi, wayland, mesa, webkit

I have built a Linux system with Buildroot (2021.05) to run on a raspberry pi 4. My graphics stack include using mesa (vc4, v3d, kmro), Wayland / Weston with a DRM back-end.

Also installed kmscube, which runs perfectly with the rotating cube reporting a frame rate of 60fps

The main application to be run in Weston is a wpewebkit application.

So far, the application runs but without any hardware acceleration. The reported frame-rate of the embedded browser is about 5fps.

When i exit from the application, i see the following messages displayed on the terminal

```
atomic: couldn't commit new state: Permission denied
repaint-flush failed: Permission denied
atomic: couldn't commit new state: Permission denied
repaint-flush failed: Permission denied
atomic: couldn't commit new state: Permission denied
repaint-flush failed: Permission denied
```

......

My system is setup to bypass any login prompts and start as root by editing my inittab file.

When i run the `who` command, i get nothing on the terminal.

If i run the command `whoami`, i get the output `root`.

Can someone point me to why i am getting the "permission denied" errors from Weston / mesa.